# System design for concurrent operation at one level with ordered operation at another

Tags: design

There are two logical entities, `Customer` and `Account` where a `Customer` is associated with one or more `Account`s.

How to design a system that **ensures** `Customer`s can update their `Account`s *concurrently*, but for a given `Account`, the requests should be processed in order based on a time attribute?

Example: Customer A has 2 Accounts. Customer A's 10 requests are received concurrently by the system. There are 5 requests per Account. I need to ensure that the 2 Accounts are updated concurrently, while each Account processes the requests for itself in the order as per the time attribute in the request. If each request takes 1 second to complete,then the 10 requests should get completed in 5 seconds.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the requirement. It sounds like you are simply asking that two customers can work independently, which is very common (i.e. nearly all web applications). Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JohnWu The intention is to ensure, all updates to a particular Account should always be in order. At the same time the system should be able to update multiple Accounts simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to "ensure" that by design, is to ensure that calls can not go past these invariables. In other words not letting the raw data be accessible to callers, but only through defined *behavior*. In other words still, use object-orientation.

For example make sure both `Customer` and `Account` has the defined behavior only, with all others (like data) being inaccessible from the outside.

Something like this:

```java
public class Customer {
   public CompletableFuture<...> someRequest(...) {
      ...
      return allOf(
         accounts.forEach(a -> a.someRequest(...)).toArray(...));
   }
}
```

So this would mean the `Customer` will always do everything in parallel. There is no way around it, since this is the "way in".

I used Java here, use the appropriate non-blocking constructs of your language.

```java
public class Account {
   public CompletableFuture<...> someRequest(...) {
      return scheduleSingleThreaded(...some date + work...)
   }
}
```

So the `Account` will always schedule a job based on a given time. The scheduler runs on a single thread, therefore will always execute tasks sequentially. I left out the exact implementation, it is not difficult, and it is not the point.

The point is, that objects should take responsibility for their invariants, then you'll be safe. Make wrong functionality syntactically impossible to write. It is usually not possible to do that for everything, you'll have to choose your battles. But this one alone is easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities of concurrency here:

For each account, do all the work parallel.   Secondly, for all the
accounts, do the work in parallel. Thirdly, for all the accounts, do
the work sequentially.

1. If you choose the first choice, 2 account with 5 requests, it should
   complete in around 2 seconds as you will concurrently execute 5
   requests for each account.  For each account, run these 5 updates
   parallel.   This is running the account sequentially but the updates
   in parallel.
2. The second way is running both accounts at the same
   time.  In this case, it should take around 1 second as all 10
   requests will be running at the same time.
3. The third way is running both accounts at the same time, but the
   requests will be run sequentially.  **I think this is your desire.**  As
   indicated this will take approx 5 seconds.  So, you will have 2
   tasks running at once with each process running the 5 updates
   sequentially.

All of this came be done with threads or async callouts.

Many languages offer concurrency in the form of threads or asynchronous callouts.   For example, in C# here is an asynchronous example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431494/how-to-use-await-in-a-loop

This can be applied to all 3 cases depending on what level you want to apply the concurrency for.